# oauth signature does not match in rest api

Tags: wordpress, oauth

I am using rest api to post to wordpress. For authentication i stick with oauth1 .I installed oauth1 plugin and json rest api plugin in wordpress. I am using 2 leg authentication

https://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/wiki/ConsumerHowTo#OAuth_Consumer

After putting key secret and the url i got the following error

**ExceptionRequest failed with code 401: OAuth signature does not match**

can anybody pls figure out why this happen? what all modifications i need to make?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that signature request is handled correctly:
http://oauth1.wp-api.org/docs/basics/Signing.html

If you're using POSTMAN you can set it to OAuth 1.0 under Authorization and then select the options

- Add empty params to signature
- Encode OAuth signature
- Save helper data to request

Also, the WP API OAuth1 plugin only supports 3 leg authentication

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was fixed by replacing '**http**' with '**https**' as I was forcing **https** in my server but was using '**http**' when calling the API. So, be careful about it and hopefully it will fix the issue.